# Php code for autofit image

Tags: javascript, php, image, thumbnails

I am using a php code for making thumbnails and fitting them. I attached a picture of what i want. The script I am usig is stretching image. Those scripts not fitting image width wise and height wise.

Can anybody please help me in sorting this issue. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what is wrong with your code since you havent posted it, but here is a handy function which I used to create thumbnails

```
function make_thumb($src, $dest, $desired_width) {

    /* read the source image */
    $source_image = imagecreatefromjpeg($src);
    $width = imagesx($source_image);
    $height = imagesy($source_image);

    /* find the "desired height" of this thumbnail, relative to the desired width  */
    $desired_height = floor($height * ($desired_width / $width));

    /* create a new, "virtual" image */
    $virtual_image = imagecreatetruecolor($desired_width, $desired_height);

    /* copy source image at a resized size */
    imagecopyresampled($virtual_image, $source_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $desired_width, $desired_height, $width, $height);

    /* create the physical thumbnail image to its destination */
    imagejpeg($virtual_image, $dest);
}
```

**$src:**    Url to your image
**$des:**    Where you want the thumbnail to be
**$width:**  Width of your thumbnail

[This code is from here](http://davidwalsh.name/create-image-thumbnail-php)